# Create form inside for loop

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeignitor and am very new to it so sorry in advance if the question is senseless,but i'm stuck with certain requirement while coding.I have a for loop as below:

```
<?php foreach($messages as $req):?>
  //This loop will execute depending on number of rows and is working fine.

 <?php echo form_open('message/addFrom_masterlist','id="myform"'); ?>
 //form is having input fields.

 <?php echo form_close();?>

 \\this acts as a submit button to my form which submits the form using javascript. 
    <input type="button" name="button" id="b1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Submit"/>

<?php endforeach; ?>

//Below is javascript code for from submit.
<script>
                function myFunction1() {
                document.getElementById("myform").submit();
            }
```

the problem is i want the id name for form to be unique since each time a button is clicked same form is being submitted.I don't want to use the submit button inside the form.Please someone help me

Comment: How you will identify which form will be submitted?

Comment: You can't submit a form without a submit button, You can send form data without submit button using ajax only;

Comment: The idea to have single submit button for multiple forms is not good. as @itzmukeshy7 says ajax is the only way in your scenario. I also feel you are complicating the situation due to misunderstanding the requirement. explain the scenario briefly.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<?php foreach($messages as $req):?>
<?php $count = 1; ?>
  //This loop will execute depending on number of rows and is working fine.

 <?php echo form_open('message/addFrom_masterlist','id="myform$count"'); ?>
 //form is having input fields.

 <?php echo form_close();?>

 \\this acts as a submit button to my form which submits the form using javascript. 
    <input type="button" name="button" id="b1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction<?php echo $count; ?>()" value="Submit"/>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

//Below is javascript code for from submit.

<?php 
$arrayCount = count($messages);
if(!empty($arrayCount)){
    for($i=1; $i<= $arrayCount; $i++){
?>
<script>
    function myFunction<?php echo $arrayCount; ?>() {
        document.getElementById("myform<?php echo $arrayCount; ?>").submit();
    }
</script>
<?php 
    } 
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you!!
Note: But the your concept like this is not good.